# IE10 svg pointer-events

Tags: html, windows-8, svg, scroll, internet-explorer-10

I have a div container with scrollable content. And I need to make a brightness settings for the user. For example:

```
<div>
    <div style="overflow-y: auto">
        <div>some long content</div>
    </div>
    <svg:svg style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;
                    opacity: 0.5" pointer-events="none">
        <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"></svg:rect>
    </svg:svg>
</div>
```

The result is acceptable. But... When I scroll content with a mouse wheel or keyboard all works as expected. But if I try to scroll content with a touch device nothing happen. Trying to listen to pointer events on scrollable container show that all is fine. The events are raised. What could prevent content from scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

I reworked little bit your html, maybe this addresses your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/krul/VZtaD/1/

```
    <svg style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;
                opacity: 0.5" pointer-events="none">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"></rect>
</svg>
```